# Sprout Forms Issue

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Curious if anyone else has encountered this error with their Sprout Forms; I'm working on some redesigns to a site that uses Sprout Forms for their contact page but whenever I go to add or modify a field the modal window is blank. [image: blank modal]

Comment: Per Ben's answer, this looks like a bug. Ping [Sprout support](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/request/support) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely cause of this behavior is a conflict with another plugin you have installed. So far, this has typically been because of a bug in another plugin.

Try disabling or uninstalling the other plugins you have installed in a test environment and see if you can track down a specific plugin that causes the issue. It's likely that some code will need to be updated to fix the issue either via a bug report or manually.

If you get stuck or are not comfortable with troubleshooting what might be happening in the code, please reach out to [Sprout support](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/request/support) and we can help troubleshoot. We'll likely need to know more details about what the other plugin in question is doing and see the code.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I turned off the Smart Maps plugin that hasn't been working right and now the Sprout plugin is working.